# Updates to 16.04 leads some inconsistency

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, upgrade, 16.04, updates

I tried to upgrade Linux from 14.04 to 16.04. After installing all new packages, it showed that Octave cannot be installed for same reasons (I don't know if this is relevant to the problem below).

I then rebooted the laptop to complete the upgrade. When restarting, I saw a line of command shows that the /dev/sda2 has an inconsistency (It asked me to do fsck). By doing some search, I did "fsck /dev/sda2" to fix the issues.

[image]

After entering the system, I found that I cannot install or update any software. The software updater shows that "There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon". It seems that the inconsistency is still there. The update seems successful, but leaves some issues.

Then I run dpkg configure. It failed:

```
>>>rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
>>>sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up octave (4.0.0-3ubuntu9.1) ...
error: save: unable to open output file 'usr/share/octave/octave_package'
error: called from
    pkg at line508 column 9
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg error while cleaning up:
 unable to open/create new triggers deferred file '/var/lib/dpkg/troggers/...'
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
    unable to flush updated status of 'gconf2': Read-only file system
```

How can I fix this problem?

========================================================================
2016.8.3
When I try to go to recovery mode, I select the 4.4.0 one. 
[image]

Without going to the menu that I can select "root", I see this error.
[image]

Then I reboot and try the 3.13.0 one. I can go to the menu and fix all errors (step 3). But when I select dpkg, I see this:
[image]
It seems that it is because of read-only system or files?

Answer (score 0):

1. boot into recovery mode
2. choose root
3. enter: sudo fsck -f /
4. repeat step 3 until there are no errors
5. reboot into recovery mode again
6. choose dpkg and let it try to repair any errors there
7. reboot and see if you're OK now

Comment: Status please. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi, @heynnema I have updated the question.

Comment: Go back to root. Confirm that my step 3 runs clean. Then type in "dpkg --configure -a" (that's two hyphens in front of configure).

Comment: Now, do not see any error in the recovery mode. But I run dpkg and get the "read-only" issue. Actually, when reboot, sometimes I am brought to Busybox, where I can see inconsistency.

Comment: Did you try the dpkg --configure -a command? If so, then type: "sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock" and then try again.

Comment: I deleted the lock file and used fsck to fix inconsisency. But then I find that the dpkg folder is gone under /var/lib. So I cannot run "dpkg --configure -a". Also, I cannot enter into Ubuntu now. After system selection, the screen becomes dark forever. I can only use recovery mode now.

Comment: Bad to worse. Shesh. fsck runs clean now, yes? In root console mode again, recreate the dpkg folder: cd /var/lib, sudo mkdir dpkg, sudo chmod 755 dpkg, reboot, see what you've got. If not good, try booting prior kernel 3.13.0-92. Report back.

Comment: I cannot create the folder dpkg. It says read-only file system

Comment: "sudo mount -o remount,rw  /" or "sudo mount -o remount,rw  /dev/sda2 /". They want us to move this discussion to chat, and I've never done that before, so I don't know how/if I can stay in contact, but I'll try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43543/discussion-between-heynnema-and-munichong).

Comment: Hi, I created the dpkg folder. But it still didn't work because it can't find another folder. So I reinstalled Ubuntu today as suggested by my friend. I think it is much easier. Still thanks for your help.